# Error Code: ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH

Tags: xconnect

I am getting below error while installing sitecore 9.01.

> Error Code: ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH More Information: The
> application pool that you are trying to use has the
> 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to ''. This application requires
> 'v4.0'.  Learn more at:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH.

In application pool xconnect status is stopped and .net clr version is no managed code.

Answer (score 1):

So set your app pool to use .CLR Runtime 4.0, as the message says.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing this via Sitecore Install Framework (SIF), then you can add a `ManagedRuntimeVersion` property to the `CreateAppPool` task in the JSON config file.

Here is an example:

```json
"CreateAppPool": {
    "Description": "Create or updates the app pool.",
    "Type": "AppPool",
    "Params": {
        "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
        "Properties": {
            "ProcessModel": {
                "identityType": "ApplicationPoolIdentity"
            },
            // Add or update this proptery to "v4.0"
            "ManagedRuntimeVersion": "v4.0"
        }
    }
}
```